# Finding the lat-lon pairs with minimum Euclidean distance between two columns

Tags: r, location, euclidean-distance

I am trying to find the **most efficient way** to solve the following puzzle in R **without** having to use **nested** `for` loops (nested `for` loops would take forever):

Let's say we have 2 data frames `d_zone2` and `stops`. Among their columns are the three ones: `lat`, `long` and `zone,` which describe the positions of certain points on the map divided into different polygons. The `zone` column in `d_zone2` is all initialized as `NA`. Now, I want to assign the correct value to each element in the `zone` column in `d_zone2` by the rule: for each pair of lat-lon in `d_zone2`, I assign the `zone` element in `stops` if the pair of lat-lon corresponds to that `zone` element in `stops` has the minimum Euclidean distance to the pair of lat-lon in `d_zone2`.

The initial solution I thought of is arranging the data frame `stops` in an **increasing order** based on `lat`, and then `long`. Then for each pair of `lat-lon` in `d_zone2`, I can use **nested** `for` loops to go through all the successive pairs of`lat-lon` to determine where my `lat-lon` in `d_zone2` is. The code is the following:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(d_zone2)){
   for(j in 1:nrow(stops)){
     if(d_zone2$Lat[i] >= stops$Lat[j] && d_zone2$Long[i] >= stops$Lat[j] && d_zone2$Lat[i]<= stops$Lat[j+1] && d_zone2$Long[i] <= stops$Lat[j+1]){
           d_zone2$X8[i] = stops$X8[j];
    }  
  }
}
```

However, I realized that this is **not** quite right, because `d_zone2$X8[i]` might belong to `stops$X8[j+1]` (since its `lat-lon` might be **closer** to that of `stops$X8[j+1]`compared to `stops$X8[j]`). Thus, I think the **only** valid approach is to **find which** pair of `lat-lon` in `stops` that gives the **minimum** Euclidean distance to a pair of lat-lon in `d_zone2`. But I don't know how to do this in R without using **nested** `for()` loops.

**2nd approach:** Another approach is to take advantage of the list of polygons created stored in the `zone.csv` file below. Now, the solution would be to select out the bucket where a pair of `lat-lon` in `d_zone2` and `stops` fall into, then just assign the zone number assigned in `stops$X8` for that particular `lat-lon` pair to the element in `d_zone2`.

**Question:** Could anyone please help me solve this puzzle using either the **Euclidean** or **2nd** approach demonstrated above? I want to use `dplyr::select(dplyr::left_join(x = d_zone2, y = stops%>% select("Lat", "Long", X8), by = ...)`, but I am not sure how to fill in the true condition for `by=??`

[.RData file containing both data frames d_zone2 and stops. 
Warning: Quite large files!](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LTvCTGgEhgLBuuNeR_qx7At_S1yTu6Rs)

[Geo-polygon coordinates](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KDx44p_eateXieL792QIds_NiqbW9P9h)

Comment: Have a look at the `distm` function in the `geosphere` package.  You could create a distance matrix of `d_zone` against `stops` and then use `apply` and `which.min` to find the shortest distances in each row or column as appropriate.

Comment: That distance matrix would be huuuuuge.

Comment: @AndrewGustar and Martin Schmelzer: thank you so much for your input. Could you give the 2nd approach described above a try? I think it produces an even better answer to what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This takes about 15 seconds because we filter out duplicate points first. This leaves us with 5457 unique points in `d_zone2`. For each of them we compute the distance to all stops and get the index of the stop with the minimum distance. Afterwards you can match the zones by stop id to all 19228939 points.

```
library(sp)
library(data.table)

setDT(d_zone2)

stop_points <- as.matrix(stops[, 3:2])
short <- unique(d_zone2, by = c("Long", "Lat"))
short[, ZONE := stops[which.min(spDists(x = stop_points, y = cbind(Long, Lat))),]$X8, by=.(Long, Lat)]
```

Comment: That is so impressive!! Thank you so much Sir. Could you try it with the 2nd approach I just added, just to check whether the result is the same? I think 2nd approach would give a more accurate answer.

Comment: So `X8` is the *zone*  in `stops`?

Comment: Yes Sir! Those are the stops I want to assign to `d_zone2$X8`

Comment: I tried executing your code, but somehow the result is full of `NA` for the column `X8`. I tried changing `stops$X8 <- as.numeric(stops$X8)`, but do not get anything better. See the image here for reference on the result: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1cH1hQ0deBoomelDa5KwiSX-1c2KDJEXL

Could you please help inspect this, as I saw your code quite right...?

Comment: Sorry deleted something by mistake

Comment: Thanks a million times for this help!! Can you try the 2nd approach above with the dataset `Geo-polygon coordinates`? Is this approach harder to implement??

Comment: Cannot try it. But there are methods like `sp::over` or `spatialEco::point_in_poly` with which one can check in what polygon a points falls into. I'd say the second approach would be less resource intensive.